# Inserting Different Input Values Into One Column (MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, insert

I am really new to SQL, and I have this little problem :

I Have a page with many inputs, let's say

> Input1, Input2, Input3, Input4

And I have a a table

```
TABLE_A   
Col1   
Col2  
Col3
```

What I want to do is to insert `Input1` into `Col1` (which is a simple thing), and to insert all of the other inputs (2,3 and 4 ) into `Col2` separated by a SPACE OR a "|"

If anyone can help that would be wonderful.

Comment: thats a simple string concatenation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (Col1, Col2)
VALUES ('Input1', CONCAT_WS('|', 'Input2', 'Input3', 'Input4'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html) which gave you brief knowledge about separated by "SPACE" OR "|" OR ",".

In that above link check some functions with examples which help you in future also.

1. `CONCAT_WS()`      Return concatenate with separator
2. `CONCAT()`     Return concatenated string
3. `ELT()`    Return string at index number
4. `EXPORT_SET()`   Return a string such that for every bit set in the
   value bits, you get an on string and for every unset bit, you get an
   off string
5. `FIELD()`      Return the index (position) of the first argument in the
   subsequent arguments
6. `FIND_IN_SET()`  Return the index position of the first argument within
   the second argument

Use `CONCAT()` to insert different input values into one column.

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (Col1, Col2)
VALUES ('Input1', CONCAT('|', 'Input2', 'Input3', 'Input4'))
```

may this help you.

Comment: thank you for your help, but now i have another problem, wich is that i should Insert the Inpu1 one into Col1 with a prefix, so if the value of input1=50 i want to insert it in col1 like this "IC-50" with the prefix IC

Comment: @user2122969 "IC-" common for all field of database.